Hard coded paths in the yocto generated sdk/toolchain
I've generated a toolchain from a Yocto Linux build using bitbake -c populate-sdk core-image-xxxxx, but when I check the generated compiler using ldd, it shows hard-coded paths, as shown below. How can I remove or avoid these hard-coded paths?
for example when running the ldd command:
ldd aarch64-poky-linux-gcc
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff33fc5000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fee4972c000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fee49503000)
        **/work/workspace/sw/yocto/release/ubuntu22/Build/output/sdk/temp_sdk-3.1.20/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 =>** /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fee49823000)

Ideally it should be somethign like this:
ldd ./aarch64-poky-linux-gcc --help
./build/software/sw/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-gcc:
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff4159f000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2e1ecc4000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2e1ea9b000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2e1edbb000)

how can I achieve this?
I've tried setting SDK_RELOCATE_AFTER_INSTALL = "1" in the configuration and compiling again, but it didn't help:
